# How to import LSTM in Keras, Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, lstm

When try to import the LSTM layer I encounter the following error:

```
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
```

> No module named 'LSTM'

So, I tried to download this module from website and another problem is the file type is `.tar` I don't know how to install it.

Comment: What keras version are you using? Can you successfully import keras? Also try `from keras.layers import LSTM`

Answer (score 3):

Use this one:
`from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM`

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work in my project (with tensorflow 2):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
```

Answer (score 0):

try
`from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM`